# Adding and removing tab pages at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, forms

I have a program that I want each person to have their own tab, each tab would be identical, however I would like to remove a tab if I need to.

```
private void addPerson(string name)
{
  TabPage tmp = new TabPage();
  ListView tmpList = new ListView();
  Button tmpButton = new Button();
  this.SuspendLayout();
  this.tabFrame.SuspendLayout();
  tmp.SuspendLayout();
  tmpList.SuspendLayout();
  tmpButton.SuspendLayout();
  ...
  //build the controll itself
  tmp.Controls.Add(tmpButton);
  tmp.Controls.Add(tmpList);
  tmp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
  tmp.Name = name.Replace(' ', '_');
  tmp.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
  tmp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 240);
  tmp.TabIndex = 3;
  tmp.Text = name;
  tmp.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
  //add it to frame
  this.tabFrame.Controls.Add(tmp);
  tmpButton.ResumeLayout(true);
  tmpList.ResumeLayout(true);
  tmp.ResumeLayout(true);
  this.tabFrame.ResumeLayout(true);
  this.ResumeLayout(true);
{
```

Name will be in the form "Scott Chamberlain" so I remove the spaces and use underscores for the name field. I can add tabs fine, they show up correctly formated, however when I try to remove the tab using the code:

```
private void removePerson(string name)
{
  this.SuspendLayout();
  this.tabFrame.SuspendLayout();
  this.tabFrame.Controls.RemoveByKey(name.Replace(' ', '_'));
  this.tabFrame.ResumeLayout(true);
  this.ResumeLayout(true);
}
```

The tab does not disappear from my program. What am I missing to remove a tab?

Comment: Have you debugged your code during the removePerson call? See what controls the tabFrame contains and what their Name properties are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/images/works-on-my-machine-starburst.png))</sub>

Creating a simple `TabPage` with a specific `Name` and adding it to `Controls` or `TabPages` works and so does removing it with `RemoveByKey` on both `Controls` and `TabPages`.

Is there any code that might later change the name?

Comment: Yes, it turns out i was passing a blank field in to name, I was not getting the text from a comboBox correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabFrame.TabPages` instead of tabFrame.Controls, for both the Add() and RemoveByKey() operations.

TabPages is a more specified version of Controls, and if such a situation occurs you are better of with the more specialized option.

Comment: TabPageCollection doesn't do much more than ControlCollection, except only allowing you to add TabPages.